# Custom dynamic authorization of images using imageresizer

Tags: authorization, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

Am trying out ImageResizer and am looking for a good method to dynamically Authorize user access to images(and other files) based on role, group etc thus restricting image access. I read that ImageResizer support Url Authorization, but unsure to wich extent(only that if i implement it will follow or there are helpers for this). Preferably a soultion that would work with their disk cache module as well. Seen some generic information regarding implementing custom url authorization, but unsure if its just a matter of setting up authorization for the image paths as one would any other resource then let imageresizer work against that. Or if some logic should e connected to imageresizer. Found some nfo here regarding url authorization in general but i guess that im not the first about to implement this combination?

The optimal setup as i see would be a restriction where no files (thumbs, images, cached images or otherwise) would be available online if authentication havent granted access.

So looking for more info / details regarding a sound and decently secure implementation of this, perhaps sample implementation / code of this exists somewhere i havent found?

**Edit:** Computer Linguist link gave me much of what i was looking for. Two things struck me though. 
1. Is there any best practises redarding what should go in a event handler or i can just build a service for this specific purpose and make use of it in the handler?
2. Since this will be triggered for every image i guess that avoid doing direct dbcalls for permission checks(ie try to device a method of caching the permissions for the respective user)? Or the practicle implications of this are usually so small that it doesnt matter? When thinking of it, does User.IsInRole not do direct dbcalls for determining membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-thinking this.

ImageResizer applies identical security to both source files, results, and cached images.

It follows the URL Authorization rules, but permits you to have complete control over all image authorization via the `Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage` event.

Handle that event, and you have access to all request data imaginable, and you can set the event AllowAccess variable to permit or deny the request based on any logic you desire. This event occurs after all URL rewriting has taken place, so this is the most accurate place to do authorization *if* your rules are based on physical file path instead of visible path.

Also, any generic AuthorizeRequest-level work you do will be respected by ImageResizer, as it doesn't activate until PostAuthorizeRequest.

ImageResizer events: http://imageresizing.net/docs/events

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that gave me much of what i was looking for.as a sidenot i noticed that authorizeimage riggered on resize only while postrewrite triggered on unaltered views as well. I edited my post above, if you have input on tha ill be greatful for it as well.

Comment: ImageResizer tries to be non-intrusive, so unless it needs to be involved in a request, it won't. I'm curious why you're not using URL Auth Roles support, it seems like it would be a good match. And if you want more control, use the HttpApplication.Authorize event.

Comment: Also, db hits are *very* expensive for individual images. Make sure you're using a Provider that does in-proc caching of user auth info. 1 DB hit for 100 images is ok, one for each will kill you.

Comment: Regarding url auth roles support. The problem with the built in roles support is, as i see, if you want each users images to be access according to each users preference. For example if each user had a user 'whitelist' or userscop wich are the only ones getting access to the images that that user uploads.
I cant at this moment see that happening without custom authorization management.

Comment: Regarding how to implement the access restriction is also a question . Implementing custom url authorization instead of manipulating imageresizer events is as i also seen before the alternative? As i see it a structure where each user has his / her subfolder and that folder is restricted to his / her specifications could be a solution. But then the same must be applied to for example imageresizers diskcache folder(dont know at this time how that structure is built, if it can be made to reflect the originating structure?) But the key is different access level for each user.

Comment: With regards to my needs, Scenario: We need two settings, private and all members can access. 
We have an area where user can publish selected images publically no matter there accessability on the main site.
My thought where getting user privacy setting when needing it in the url auth and caching it. 
Then deny access if folder matching users name is requested and privacy is set to private. Regarding publish same image on another area i dont know for sure. 
Can page / url where access come from be filtered perhaps?

Comment: ImageResizer's disk cache won't circumvent your code in any way - the request still comes in under the browser-visible URL whether the image is cached or not. This question really has nothing whatsoever to do with ImageResizer, and everything to do with ASP.NET authorization designs. I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: I agree and will do so. WIll pan out the specific questions since this is getting vague. Thanks for your help.